# installation problem when i try to install react app

Tags: node.js

I'm Juan,
And also I'm a student studying Computer Science.
First time I come to learn about nodejs. When I try to create react app, I've got the above problem in cmd. So, Help me to solve this problem. So, that I could proceed to learn more about node.js.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAC6j.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The command for creating react app is:
**npx create-react-app your-app-name**

Check out the documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

Comment: This will fail in the same way. The domain name "registry.npmjs.org" is failing to resolve. The user should check his DNS settings. If he is relying on his ISPs DNS servers he should consider switching it to Cloudflare's or Google's